# Magento : Layered Navigation Search Filter

Tags: attributes, filter, search, magento1.9.2.4

I am trying filter layer search. 
How to make filter layered search with four attributes. 
How to make a filter search with category, sub-category, width, height, price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the easiest way for filtere layered navigation search 
We need to give permission to attributes to 'Yes' to show in search.